# Сохранить сцену в unity3d из c#

Tags: unity3d, save

Мне нужно сохранить все объекты на сцене (Не только транформ, но и скрипты с их полями) из c# скрипта, а потом загрузить обратно.

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите класс [EditorSceneManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.html):

1. [открыть сцену](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.OpenScene.html)
2. [сохранить сцену](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.SaveScene.html) / [сохранить несколько сцен](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.SaveScenes.html) / [сохранить все открытые сцены](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.SaveOpenScenes.html)

Естественно, работать этот класс будет только в самом редакторе Unity. В билде так делать не получится

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне как раз нужно, чтобы в билде работало

Comment: @Александр это у вас не получится реализовать

Comment: Мне тоже что-то подобное надо,что бы реализовать сохранение